# ajax post javascript variable to php in same page

Tags: php, jquery

i write sample code to ajax post **javaxcript varible to php** in 2 page, test.php and validate.php.

**test.php :**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js" ></script>

</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="enter Your name...." /><br/>
<input type="text" id="age" placeholder="enter Your age...." /><br/>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="post();">
</form>
<div id="result" ></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function post()
 {
var name=$('#name').val();
var age=$('#age').val();
$.post('validate.php',{postname:name,postage:age},
function(data)
{
if (data=="1")
    {
$('#result').html('you are over 18 !');
}
if (data=="0")
{
$('#result').html('you are under 18 !');
}
});
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**validate.php**

```
<?php
$name=$_POST['postname'];
$age=$_POST['postage'];

if ($age>=18)
{
echo "1";
}
else
{
echo "0";
}
?>
```

**how can i write/change above code in same page ?? and validate.php insert in test.php ??**

added after first answer :
"but i dont have/use any button or  in my page. 
and where can i insert validate.php code in test.php. please help by insert complete correct code."

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `submit()` method to your `<form>` rather than attaching the event to the submit button.

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(){
    post();
    return false;
});
```

At the moment I think your form is submitted no matter what, you have to either `return false` on submit or `preventDefaults()`

A good idea is also to add an ID to your form in case you have more than one on your page and use the relevant selector in the `.on` event handler such as

`$(document).on('submit', $('#form-id'), function(){ ... });`

Comment: but i dont have any submit() button or any <form> in design. and where insert validate.php code ?

Comment: Have a look at this [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/59nvW/)  however you don't really need Ajax.

Comment: i have condition in javascript, and depend on result in same page php code echo some value. how can add php codes in that code ?(http://fiddle.jshell.net/59nvW/) , javascript must be run first and then php .

Comment: If you only have to compare the age input with a given number (18) then you don't need Ajax ($.post), the following would do.  `function post()
{
    var age=$('#age').val();

    if (age >= 18)
    {
        $('#result').html('you are over 18 !');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#result').html('you are under 18 !');
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

ajax is use for exchanging data with a server. If you want write code in same page so reload page and write validate.php code above of test.php like this

```
<?php
   //validate.php code
?>
<form action=test.php type=POST>
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="enter Your name...." /><br/>
  <input type="text" id="age" placeholder="enter Your age...." /><br/>
  <input type="button" value="submit">
</form>
```